# Move a UserControl in MainPage.xaml in Windows 10 application using VisualStateManager

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, visualstatemanager

I have a UserControl in my page (XAML) which represents a toolbar, across the top of the page which has three buttons. Since this is a Windows 10 app, I would like it so that when the screen width is wide, that this top toolbar moves along the left edge of the screen so that it shows the toolbar vertically. I tried using the VisualStateManager VisualStates but that only helps change properties and not elements. I need to change the ColumnDefinitions to RowDefinitions in order to display the buttons vertically.

The only solution I have now is to create a second UserControl (VerticalToolBar.xaml) and use the VSM to hide and unhide both. But I'm sure there is an easier solution to something that might be common. I'd like to use one UserControl because right now I'm duplicating their code behind. They behave the same.

Here is the XAML for TopHorizontalToolBar.xaml:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Innobec.Mobile.Apps.CityScope.UserControls.TopHorizontalToolBar"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Innobec.Mobile.Apps.CityScope.UserControls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="80"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="MainToolbar">
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="Red">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="pinButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Background="Red" Click="pinButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource TopHorizontalToolBarButtonStyle}">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Top-Pin-Icon-60px.png" Stretch="None"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="newsButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Background="Red" Click="newsButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource TopHorizontalToolBarButtonStyle}">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Top-News-Icon-60px.png" Stretch="None"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="weatherButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Background="Red" Click="weatherButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource TopHorizontalToolBarButtonStyle}">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Top-Weather-Icon-60px.png" Stretch="None"/>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

My VerticalToolBar is similar except it uses . On my MainPage.xaml I have the following which shows where I place these UserControls:

```
    <Page 
x:Class="Innobec.Mobile.Apps.CityScope.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Innobec.Mobile.Apps.CityScope"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps"
xmlns:toolbars="using:Innobec.Mobile.Apps.CityScope.UserControls"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="SlideInfoUp">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LocationDetails" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" EnableDependentAnimation="True">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25" Value="130"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="SlideInfoDown">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LocationDetails" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" EnableDependentAnimation="True">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WindowStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="660"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="TopBarGrid.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Target="LeftBarGrid.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Target="LeftBarGrid.(Grid.RowSpan)" Value="3"/>
                    <Setter Target="LeftBarGrid.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Target="LeftBarGrid.Width" Value="Auto"/>
                    <Setter Target="ContentGrid.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Target="ContentGrid.(Grid.Column)" Value="1"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="TopBarGrid.(Grid.Row)" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Target="TopBarGrid.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="LeftColumn" Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="TopBarGrid">
        <toolbars:TopHorizontalToolBar/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="LeftBarGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="60">
        <toolbars:VerticalToolBar />
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid  Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>                        
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>                    
            <ListView x:Name="itineraryListView" 
                        Grid.Row="1"  
                        Margin="24,24,0,0" 
                        SelectionMode="None">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RelativePanel Margin="0,24,0,0">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="address" 
                                        Width="100" 
                                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                        Text="{Binding FormattedAddress}"/>
                            <ListView 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding ItineraryInfosAtPoint}" 
                                RelativePanel.RightOf="address" 
                                SelectionMode="None">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
                        </RelativePanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>                  
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <maps:MapControl x:Name="InfoMap"
                             Loaded="InfoMap_Loaded"                              
                             MapElementClick="InfoMap_MapElementClick"  
                             TransitFeaturesVisible="False" 
                             BusinessLandmarksVisible="False" 
                             LandmarksVisible="True" 
                             ZoomLevelChanged="InfoMap_ZoomLevelChanged"                                 
                             MapServiceToken="qB0QfPpDYI6Qh8SWJvS5~x5_U5L-2_-eVF0AE_2qg2w~AuuXeJ_QLZ_6APb7Y3vr3x_opC-CkytS298EJUAjPpPo6pSj1hzYpCIdCTUkH1pf"/>
        </Grid>           
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"><!--Grid.ColumnSpan="2"-->
        <Viewbox MaxWidth="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <toolbars:LocationDetails x:Name="LocationDetails" Height="0"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <toolbars:BottomToolBar x:Name="BottomToolBar"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Didn't get very familiar with UWP yet, some I'm not so sure to what extent it supports stuff, but you can try putting a ContentPresenter and switching the ContentTemplate.

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. I'm new to XAML. I read about ContentPresenter and ContentTemplate, but I don't get how to do the switching. Any examples out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a StackPanel to hold your buttons instead of a Grid. Then, you could change the Orientation between Horizontal and Vertical via Visual States to quickly switch the layout of the panel.

A more Windows 10 option would be to use the brand new RelativePanel to hold your buttons. This control allows you to define the position of the children inside it relative to each other. For your horizontal layout each button could be set to the right of the previous one and for vertical layout each could be set below. These relative properties can also be changed via Visual States. Your control above would look like this for the Horizontal View.

```
 <RelativePanel >
        <Button x:Name="pinButton" Background="Red" Click="pinButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource TopHorizontalToolBarButtonStyle}">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Top-Pin-Icon-60px.png" Stretch="None"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="newsButton"  Background="Red" Click="newsButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource TopHorizontalToolBarButtonStyle}"
                RelativePanel.RightOf="pinButton">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Top-News-Icon-60px.png" Stretch="None"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="weatherButton"  Background="Red" Click="weatherButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource TopHorizontalToolBarButtonStyle}"
                RelativePanel.RightOf="newsButton">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Top-Weather-Icon-60px.png" Stretch="None"/>
        </Button>
 </RelativePanel>
```

This is a good blog post that goes more in depth on the RelativePanel and setting up Visual States for it:
http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2015/04/building-adaptive-layout-in-windows-10-with-relativepanel-and-adaptivetrigger/

Comment: I tried the RelativePanel and it works as far as what I was trying to do. But I lose one feature when using it. The ability to evenly space my buttons horizontally or vertically. With the RelativePanel, they get glued together next to each other. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: That is one of the best parts of using the Grid. I'm not sure if there is an elegant way to mimic that functionality with the RelativePanel via XAML. One solution that would work is to subscribe to the SizeChanged event of the RelativePanel and manually set the sizes of your buttons. There may be a better way but it does still save you from having two separate user controls at least.

Comment: Thanks @Rich I'm going to eventually figure that part but this would suffice as an answer for me. The RelativePanel is a better approach.

Comment: I haven't been able to evenly distribute the buttons in the RelativePanel. I tried with the Grid but no success. I'll create a new question for this.